# How do I get all of the non excluded items in this list using an XPATH?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have the following xml file:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <name>Suede Shoe</name>
        <category>Footwear</category>
        <price>£90.00</price>
        <tags>
            <footwear />
            <shoes />
        </tags>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Leather Shoe</name>
        <category>footwear</category>
        <price>£90.00</price>
        <tags>
            <footwear />
        </tags>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Canvas Shoe</name>
        <category>Footwear</category>
        <price>£90.00</price>
        <tags>
            <footwear exclude="true"/>
            <shoes/>
        </tags>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Toecap Shoe</name>
        <category>Footwear</category>
        <price>£90.00</price>
        <tags>
            <footwear exclude="true"/>
        </tags>
    </item>
</items>
```

I would like to select all of the items that contain one of my selected tags, but not bring back a result if the tag is excluded.

examples:

tags: footwear
returns:  1, 2

tags: shoes
returns 1, 3

tags: footwear|shoes
returns 1,2,3

Any help please?

Before including the 'exclude' requirement this xpath was working:

```
//tags[implode('|', $tags)]/parent::item
```

the tag "footwear" that is not excluded.

Comment: It is not clear what you exactly want the XPath expression to return -- what "1, 2" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the footwear|shoes the XPath may look like

```
//tags[footwear[not( @exclude='true' )]|shoes[not( @exclude='true' )]]/parent::item
```

This will show 1,2,3

Comment: @alex: Check my answer for a more general forward expression and without extensions functions like in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath 1.0 expression:

```
/items/item[
   tags/*[
      not(@exclude='true')
   ][
      contains(
         concat('|',$tags,'|'),
         concat('|',name(),'|')
      )
   ]
]
```

With $tags variable set as `'footwear'` string selects:

```
<item>
    <name>Suede Shoe</name>
    <category>Footwear</category>
    <price>£90.00</price>
    <tags>
        <footwear />
        <shoes />
    </tags>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Leather Shoe</name>
    <category>footwear</category>
    <price>£90.00</price>
    <tags>
        <footwear />
    </tags>
</item>
```

With $tags variable set as `'shoes'` string selects:

```
<item>
    <name>Suede Shoe</name>
    <category>Footwear</category>
    <price>£90.00</price>
    <tags>
        <footwear />
        <shoes />
    </tags>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Canvas Shoe</name>
    <category>Footwear</category>
    <price>£90.00</price>
    <tags>
        <footwear exclude="true" />
        <shoes />
    </tags>
</item>
```

With $tags variable set as `'footwear|shoes'` string selects:

```
<item>
    <name>Suede Shoe</name>
    <category>Footwear</category>
    <price>£90.00</price>
    <tags>
        <footwear />
        <shoes />
    </tags>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Leather Shoe</name>
    <category>footwear</category>
    <price>£90.00</price>
    <tags>
        <footwear />
    </tags>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Canvas Shoe</name>
    <category>Footwear</category>
    <price>£90.00</price>
    <tags>
        <footwear exclude="true" />
        <shoes />
    </tags>
</item>
```